# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException'

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am developing a C# application which takes some data from a text field and once the save button is clicked saves data to a SQLite DB. But I am getting an error when I click on the save button. I have tried searching a solution for it online. But nothing worked out. I keep getting the error in this line:

```
sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is the error I am getting

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
>   Additional information: SQL logic error or missing database
>   no such table: Info

This is my code

```
private SQLiteConnection sql_con;
private SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;
private SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
private DataTable DT = new DataTable();

//private Container components = null;
public EnterDataFrm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

//method to set the coonection string
private void SetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        sql_con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\josriskandarajah\Documents\Sample Projects\sqlite\sqlite\sqlite\bin\TestDb.sqlite;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

//method for executing query
private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
{
    SetConnection();
    sql_con.Open();

    sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
    sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;

    sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql_con.Close();
}

private void Add()
{
    string txtSQLQuery = "insert into Info (ID,FirstName,LastName,Age) values ('" + this.txtID.Text + "','" + this.txtFirstName.Text + "','" + this.txtLastName.Text + "','" + this.txtAge.Text + "')";
    ExecuteQuery(txtSQLQuery);
}


private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add();
}
```

Comment: What does `txtQuery` contain?

Comment: @john, what does the Info-table look like?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko See the call in the add method

Comment: wrong table name or create the table "Info" first...

Comment: @Patrik Eckebrecht: you can well have an error if, say, `this.txtID.Text` contains an *apostroph*; could you, please, put a *breakpoint* and examine `txtQuery` before execution.

Comment: Are you sure, you have Info table in Testdb? Check once database and table both.

Comment: Your error clearly states the problem - it can't see the `Info` table in your database. but more importantly, PARAMETERISE THOSE VARIABLES!!!! Your code is highly vunerable to SQL injection in its current state

Comment: How many subfolders named sqlite do you really have here?

Comment: The error indicates that the table `Info` that you are trying to insert into does not yet exist. Btw: your code is wide open to [SQL injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com). Even if this is just for practicing, you should also practice to write safe (sanitized, parameterized) sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't created table name Info with ID,FirstName ,LastName ,Age field. Also check that Data Source path exists or not.

Create table somethings like this:

```
string sql ="CREATE TABLE `Info` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `FirstName` TEXT,
    `LastName`  TEXT,
    `Age`   INTEGER
)";
```

Or You can use  **DB Browser for SQLite **Tools to create table.